# Dense ranking based on a quantity field without distinct join on two tables

Tags: php, sql

I have a very strange requirement at site. I have two tables Header and Details. I can join on two fields [Item Code] and [Contract Number] but they are not unique. But the end result which they are expecting is to select the records from the details table based on a quantity field in header. I know this sounds crazy but they don't have any other distinct joins.

Ex: **Header table**

```
Item code |Contract Number | Quantity
-------------------------------------
1000        50000              2
1000        50000              3
1000        50000              2
```

**Item Table**

```
Item code |Contract Number | Work Order
-------------------------------------
1000        50000              abc
1000        50000              def
1000        50000              ghi
1000        50000              jkl
1000        50000              mno
1000        50000              pqr
1000        50000              stv
```

**Expected Result:**

I need to pick the work orders based on quantity i.e for first row in header with quantity 2 I need to pick first two records in Item table and like wise.

Comment: Please show us expected result here

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using MySQL or SQL Server??? Your tags are confusing.

Comment: *... to pick first two records in Item table...* This makes sense only when a particular sort order is applied. Please explain how do you want to implement your requirement deterministically on a data set that you showed?

Comment: Its a legacy database(not sure what type of db/flatfiles) and I am pretty sure its against any RDBMS to have data like this.

I even tried to have the row_number generated for both the tables but no luck...I am in a big dilemma even whether its possible to adpot it in SQL.

Comment: its not possible as there is no unique identifier. your client will ask anything from you its your job to say no for something that is technically impossible

Comment: In all major RDBMSes order of the records is not guaranteed until you specify `ORDER BY`. Therefore in your case there is no way to deterministically tell which items belongs to which header. You have to have al least some sort of `header_id` in `header` table and `item_id` in `item` table. Better yet `header_id` as FK in `item` table

Comment: I tried putting across the same words to them but never got a single reply on that. But I am thinking if its techinically possible to account for that..:(

Comment: Is it possible to Pick the top rows based on quantity then mark them as status->used then pick the next top columns?
or
Is it possible to write a stored procedure which does the job for me?

Comment: Again it's totally depends on your RDBMS. If you can't even tell us what it is how can we help you?

Comment: I fixed this issue by creating a dummy table and inserting rows based on my quantity. Then I used row_number() on both tables to match against exact rows. This has fixed the problem for now :)